# How do I convert SSIS projects created in BIDS 2005 to BIDS 2008?

Tags: bids, ssis

I have a number of dtsx projects created under Visual Studio 2005.

When I try to convert the solution to 2008 it converts fine but then the .dtproj file can't be loaded:

`myProj.dtproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.dtproj) is not supported by this version of the application.`

I have SQL Server 2005 installed but I got rid of Visual Studio 2005 as I am moving all my projects to Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the shell for BIDS. You can't use VS 2008 with SQL Server 2005 dtsx.

Comment: how do I do that? Does that mean I have to keep VS2005? I was hoping to completely get rid of it.

Comment: Run the setup in Tools subfolder. Choose Client Components -> Business Intelligence Development Studio.